# Minesweeper VB.NET issue

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, global-variables, minesweeper

So basically, i have 2 int variables, x and y i am using to create a grid of pictureboxes.

This is all fluid and built on runtime.

I am trying to specifically change the picturebox on click if mine = 2.

I cannot specifically change one, when i click any, it changes all of them.

HELP PLEASE!!

Heres my code:

```
  Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Dim images(8) As Image 'declares image array

    Dim zonesY As Integer = 50
    Dim zonesX As Integer = 50

    Dim Guy As Object
    Dim pbxNewZone As PictureBox = DirectCast(Guy, PictureBox)  'declares pbxNewZone as a picturebox variable

    Dim generator As New Random

    Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        images(0) = Image.FromFile("blank.png")
        images(1) = Image.FromFile("1.png")
        images(2) = Image.FromFile("2.png")
        images(3) = Image.FromFile("3.png")
        images(4) = Image.FromFile("4.png")
        images(5) = Image.FromFile("5.png")
        images(6) = Image.FromFile("clear.png")
        images(7) = Image.FromFile("hit.png")
        images(8) = Image.FromFile("mine.png")

        Dim x As Integer  'declares x as an integer variable
        Dim y As Integer  'declares y as an integer variable
        Me.SuspendLayout()  'suspends creation of layout

        For y = 1 To zonesY 'starts a For loop (1 to zonesY number of loops)
            For x = 1 To zonesX  'starts a For loop (1 to zonesX number of loops)
                Dim zonesize1 As Integer
                Dim zonesize2 As Integer
                Dim mine As Integer

                pbxNewZone = New PictureBox

                Dim blockStatus As Integer
                Dim allZones As Integer
                allZones = zonesX * zonesY
                blockStatus = generator.Next(0, allZones)

                pbxNewZone.Name = (zonesX * (y - 1)) + x
                If blockStatus < (allZones / 10) Then
                    mine = 1
                    If mine = 1 Then
                        pbxNewZone.Image = images(8)
                    End If
                Else
                    mine = 2
                    If mine = 2 Then
                        pbxNewZone.Image = images(0)
                    End If
                End If
                pbxNewZone.Height = 16
                pbxNewZone.Width = 16
                pbxNewZone.Tag = 0
                zonesize1 = pbxNewZone.Height 'sets out all of the boxes on the form.
                zonesize2 = pbxNewZone.Width
                pbxNewZone.Left = ((x - 1) * zonesize1 + 15)
                pbxNewZone.Top = ((y - 1) * zonesize2 + 15)
                Me.Controls.Add(pbxNewZone)
                '  Wire this control up to an appropriate event handler
                AddHandler pbxNewZone.Click, AddressOf pbxNewZoneClicked

            Next
        Next
        Me.Height = (pbxNewZone.Height * zonesY + 63)  'sets the height of fmmGame
        Me.Width = (pbxNewZone.Width * zonesX + 40)  'sets the width of frmGame

        checkBlank()

    End Sub

    Public Sub checkBlank()

    End Sub

    Private Sub pbxNewZoneClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        ReDim x
        Do While y = 1 'starts a For loop (1 to zonesY number of loops)
            Do While x = 1  'starts a For loop (1 to zonesX number of loops)
                MsgBox("you have clicked " & x & ", " & y)
            Loop
        Loop
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I haven't fully read your code but your Click event seems incomplete, can you post it all? And `mine = 1
                If mine = 1 Then
                    pbxNewZone.Image = images(8)
                End If` Is redundant - why set `mine = 1` then test `If mine = 1`?

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it tries to change the pictureboxes at all. We can't help you work out why its changing all of them if you don't include the relevant code... Or maybe I'm being blind - if so you may want to draw more attention to the bit of code you think is going wrong rather than letting it get lost in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Click event, `sender` will be the clicked object so...

```
Dim pbx as PictureBox = DirectCast(sender,PictureBox)
```

...will give you a reference (as `pbx`) to the clicked PictureBox - then you can do what you need to do with it.

For ease, you may want to check the state of a given PictureBox by checking `pbx.Image` - as you do not have any custom attributes of the PictureBox.

Answer (score 4):

You're adding the same handler to all the PictureBoxes but not doing anything to the specific PictureBox that was clicked (the Sender parameter). You can use the Name or Tag properties to work out what to do with the click. You might want to extend the standard PictureBox to include extra parameters that will make this easier - x and y properties for example.

As an aside you might want to consider re-factoring form_load so that it calls a number of more discrete methods.

Comment: how can I do that, i was searching for a similar fuctionality.

Comment: You can just inherit from PictureBox and extend/override its behaviour as required. It's very straight-forward, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996443.aspx to get started.